# Detecting cycles in a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, graph, cycle

I have a table in MySQL with two (important) columns, A and B, with value referring to a package.  A row is in the table if and only if package A requires on package B.

I was hoping to **(1)** generate a graph in php, then **(2)** determine if the graph is acyclic (a DAG), and if not, print **(3)** all the cycles in the graph.

So 3 is easy enough, in theory, (Johnson's algorithm: http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf ).

(2) can be done by (3) listing no cycles, but I was wondering if there was any faster algorithms.

I'm unsure of (1) - efficiently pulling data from a table and making a graph in php that lends itself to implementing (2) and (3).  How should I do so?

---

As an aside, I also have a second table, also with two columns, having a row if and only if A conflicts with B.  I also wanted to **(4)** find cases (or verify that there are none) where:
A requires B, B requires C, but A conflicts with C

Comment: Finite, but besides that, no.  I may have a very long chain such as A=>B=>C=>...=>Z=>A.  I should also clarify that its likely to be a directed forest as opposed to just a tree (i.e. unconnected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interests of anyone who finds this topic in a search

**(1)**

```
$pkgList = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM `Packages`');
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL) {
    $pkgList[] = $row['idPackages'];
}

$reqEdgeList = array();
$conEdgeList = array();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Dependancies` WHERE `Relationship` = 'Requires'");
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL) {
    switch ($row['Relationship']) {
        case 'Requires':
            $reqEdgeList[] = array($row["DependerPackage"], $row["DependeePackage"]);
            break;
        case 'Conflicts':
            $conEdgeList[] = array($row["DependerPackage"], $row["DependeePackage"]);
            break;
    }
}
```

**(2)** and **(3)**

I ended up using the algorithm [here](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~keller/courses/cs60/s98/examples/acyclic/).  Basically by removing leaf nodes, you are either left with a (set of) loop(s) or an empty graph.

```
$allReqs = $reqEdgeList;

$noDependanciesCycle = true;

$searching = true;
while ($searching) {
    if (empty($pkgList)) {
        $searching = false;
        echo "Req is a DAG\n<br />";
    } else {
        $foundleaf = false;
        $leaf = null;
        foreach ($pkgList as $key => $l) {
            $isLeaf = true;
            foreach ($reqEdgeList as $k => $edge) {
                if ($edge[0] == $l) {
                    $isLeaf = false;
                }
            }

            if ($isLeaf) {
                $foundleaf = true;
                $leaf = $l;
            }
        }
        if ($foundleaf) {
            $pkgList = array_diff($pkgList, array($leaf));
            foreach ($reqEdgeList as $key => $value) {
                if ($value[1] == $leaf) {
                    unset($reqEdgeList[$key]);
                }
            }
            $reqEdgeList = array_values($reqEdgeList);
        } else {
            $searching = false;
            echo "Req cycle detected\n<br />";
            $noDependanciesCycle = false;
            print_r($reqEdgeList);
            echo "<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**(4)**

For finding A requires B requires C, but A conflicts with C, I used a depth first search for each conflict, starting from A, looking for C (the conflict).

```
$reqEdgeList = $allReqs;
echo "<br />\n";

$anyReqConfError = false;
foreach ($conEdgeList as $endpoints) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $startPkg = $endpoints[0];
            $endPkg = $endpoints[1];
        } else {
            $startPkg = $endpoints[1];
            $endPkg = $endpoints[0];
        }

        $marked = array();
        foreach ($allPkgs as $pkg) {
            $marked[$pkg] = false;
        }

        $queue = array();
        $queue[] = $startPkg; // enque
        $marked[$startPkg] = true;

        $searching = true;
        $found = false;
        while ($searching) {
            $v = array_shift($queue); // deque (use array_pop for stack (dfs))
            if ($v == $endPkg) {
                $searching = false;
                $found = true;
            } else {
                foreach ($reqEdgeList as $edge) {
                    if ($edge[0] == $v) {
                        $w = $edge[1];
                        if (!$marked[$w]) {
                            $marked[$w] = true;
                            $queue[] = $w;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if($searching) {
                $searching = !empty($queue);
            }
        }

        if($found) {
            echo "$startPkg requires $endPkg, but are conflicting [$endpoints[0] $endpoints[1]]\n<br />";
            $anyReqConfError = true;
            $noDependanciesCycle = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any code review in the comments for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds suspiciously like 'please help me with my homework'.

In terms of rendering the graph - have a look at graphviz - this will generate all sorts of graphs. [Here's an example](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6688-PHP-Generate-call-graphs-of-PHP-code-with-GraphViz.html) which parses PHP source code to get a call graph.

Sorry, but I'm busy enough without reading the reference you provided (but well done for providing a link to your source material) and working out the algorithm they've used then thinking about whether it is optimal.

You might want to have a look at the source code for the new PHP garbage collector - which does the same thing. (really you just need to walk the tree - if you come to a node you've already visited then you've got a loop).

Comment: Sorry if I've mislead you, but I'm not asking about how to implement an algorithm I've found, I'm asking what is the best practice for **(1)** generating a graph (as in the combinatorial/data structure kind) from MySQL data in PHP and for **(2)** graph traversal in PHP.  I'm not interested in graph drawing, but thank you for the link.

Comment: I'm not asking you to tell me if some obscure algorithm is good for my task (that is of course, my job) or even how to implement it, but instead to suggest another (if you know one) and more importantly to suggest (links to) example code related to (1) and (2).  I should also mention this isn't homework, but actual work - I've implemented graph traversal in other languages, I'm simply looking for how others have done so in PHP, specifically with MySQL data.